# How to write DL queries using java

Tags: ontology, owl

How do I connect an ontology using java?
I have created an ontology using protege.
How can I write DL queries in Java to use this ontology?

Comment: This was a valid question. I am surprised that it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) and [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/).

Answer (score 1):

DL queries are simply OWL class expressions. You can use the OWL-API as suggested, look at the example provided [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/master/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/DLQueryExample.java). If you need to perform some reasoning in order to retrieve the data of interest, add a reasoner on your classpath (Hermit, Pellet, etc...). You can also think of using the [Brain library](http://loopasam.github.io/Brain/), developed for this purpose, yet only supporting the OWL2 EL profile at the time being.