# How to convert a string to OWL Object Property in Java?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api, dlquery

I am writing a DL query parser in Java. I need to use the method getObjectPropertyValues(). how to convert a string to OWL Object Property expression in Java , please give me a sample code.

Comment: What API are you using?  The two common ones (that I'm aware of) are Jena and the OWL-API.  (I notice that you didn't specify this in [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19228798/1281433), either, but it's really needed there, too.)

Comment: Based on the method name `getObjectPropertyValues`, I expect that you're trying to use the OWL-API.  There are (at least) two methods with that name, though: `OWLReasoner.getObjectPropertyValues`, and `OWLIndividual.getObjectPropertyValues`.  Neither takes zero arguments, though.

Comment: you can also look at this example https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/master/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/DLQueryExample.java

Comment: Did you end up getting this resolved?  If you did, and one of the answers worked for you, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437), or if they didn't, you should write up what ended up working for you, and should accept it (it's not a bad thing at all to accept your own answer).  If you haven't found a solution yet, can you elaborate on the problem?  Perhaps more information will help in finding an answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You create an [`OWLObjectProperty`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLObjectProperty.html) using the aptly named [`OWLDataFactory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI iri)`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataFactory.html#getOWLObjectProperty%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI%29), and IRI has a constructor [`IRI(String)`](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/IRI.html#IRI%28java.lang.String%29). E.g., from [the examples](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java#L644) in the documentation:

```java
OWLObjectProperty prop
  = factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#propA"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the OWLAPI you can reuse the code from here for parsing a DL query:
https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/DL-Queries-with-a-real-reasoner